# Reviewing iCloud Calendars

Tags: calendar, icloud

**Question:** Is there a way to either confirm that an iCloud calendar is empty or, alternatively, to list the contents of the calendar?

**Background:** I have a number of calendars (iCloud, Google and others) that I have created over the years.  I now want to manage them down to a smaller number and remove duplicate events and actions.

Currently I am looking at my iCloud calendars.  A couple of the calendars appear to be empty because I cannot see anything from them on my calendar when I scroll back and forward through the months.  However, it's possible that the calendar my contain something that I have forgotten but don't want to lose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access iCloud calendars using the standard 
[CalDAV](http://caldav.de/) protocol. As a recent complication you need to [setup an app-specific-password](https://www.imore.com/apps-use-icloud-will-require-app-specific-passwords-starting-june-15) to access your account.

You fail to mention what programming environment you want to do this in, but:
[Building a CalDAV client](http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/)
is a great resource.
Basic stuff like listing calendars can also be done quite easily using tools like `curl` and `xmlstarlet`.

Comment: Thanks.  I learned a lot about calendars in the last few days.  The simplest way to see if they contained anything, I found, was to export the calendar into a text file and inspect it.  Thanks for the link to the CalDAV protocol.  That will prove useful down the line.